# Calculating $\oint_{\gamma}z^ndz$ for a triangle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I wish to calculate the following integral:

$$\oint_{\gamma}z^ndz$$

$\gamma$ is a triangle with vertices at $0,1,i$, in the positive direction and $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Here is what I think, please correct me if I'm wrong

For $n\ge 0$ $z^n$ is analytic on and inside the triangle, and $\gamma$ is a closed path, so $\oint_{\gamma}z^ndz=0$

For $n<0$ the function is not defined at $z=0$, so I think can't use the same theorem.

I tried calculating it using the following parameterization:

$$\gamma(t)=\begin{cases} \gamma_1 && t\in[0,1] && t \\ \gamma_2 && t\in[0,1] && (1-t) + i\cdot t \\ \gamma_3 && t\in[0,1] && (1-t)i  \end{cases}$$

But  since I don't know $n$, I don't think I can solve it.

Edit: I think I can use Green theorem, Is that right?

Comment: If $n<0$, your function is undefined at $0$, and therefore your integral doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so there must be a mistake in the question. am I right in my reasoning for $n>0$?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: It is potentially a bad premise to take $n$ *rational* since non-integral powers of complex numbers are not immediately defined in an unambiguous way. Did you mean $n \in \mathbf Z$?

Comment: @KCd you are right, fixed. I don't think it changes the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge 0$, I was correct.

For $n<0$, the function is not defined at $0$, so this integral is unsolvable.